# How to encapsulate text "nodes" but no nodes themselves?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get all text strings from a HTML code with JavaScript and encapsulate them in independent tags as children of their parents.

### Example

This is the HTML that I have:

```
<div>
    Text Text Text
    <p>
        Text Text
    </p>
    <b>
        Text Text
        <i>
            Text.
        </i>
    </b>
    Text Text Text.
</div>
```

(The code will have no tabs, it is made by the page itself in a single line.)

And this is what I would like to get:

```
<div>
    <span>Text Text Text</span>
    <p>
        <span>Text Text</span>
    </p>
    <b>
        <span>Text Text</span>
        <i>
            <span>Text.</span>
        </i>
    </b>
    <span>Text Text Text.</span>
</div>
```

I have been looking how to do it with `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `insertAdjacentHTML()`... but I do not know how to do it in a reliable way.

Do you think of any way to do it? (If possible, a way to do it in vanilla JavaScript.)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all of the page's text nodes using a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) (built by the [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) method), and then use `Node#replaceChild` to do the rest:

```js
function getTextNodes(root) {

  var tw = document.createTreeWalker(root || document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
    acceptNode: function(node) {
      return /^(STYLE|SCRIPT)$/.test(node.parentElement.tagName) ||
        /^\s*$/.test(node.data) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT : NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
    }
  })

  var result = []
  while (tw.nextNode()) result.push(tw.currentNode)
  return result
}

getTextNodes().forEach(function(n) {
  var span = document.createElement('span')
  n.parentNode.replaceChild(span, n)
  span.appendChild(n)
})

console.log(document.body.firstElementChild.innerHTML)
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div>
    Text Text Text
    <p>
      Text Text
    </p>
    <b>
        Text Text
        <i>
            Text.
        </i>
    </b> Text Text Text.
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! PD: Maybe you could have made a simpler example.